# Successive multiplications using Mathematica tools

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, complex, iteration

### Successive rotations on the unit circle

Given an arbitrary starting point $z$ on the unit circle in the complex plane, the goal is to compute a cycle of rotations by $\pi$/2 with successive multiplications by $i=\sqrt{-1}$. The output is

$$\zeta = \{ z, iz, -z, -iz\}$$

[image: Multiplication by the complex unit modulus]

### This works, but ...

My effort uses a repetition like this:
`\[Zeta] = AppendTo[\[Zeta], I Last[\[Zeta]]]`

### How to exploit Mathematica

What other methods produce this answer in a more elegant fashion?

Comment: Look at the documentation for `NestList`.

Comment: `z * I^Range[0,3]` ? (Positive integer powers are, by definition, successive multiplications, after all.)

Comment: `NestList[I # &, z, 3]`

Comment: `NumberFieldRootsOfUnity[I]` has wrong sequence.

Comment: Try this: `\[Rho]*Table[E^(I*\[CurlyPhi] + I*n*\[Pi]/2), {n, 1, 6}] /. \[Rho] -> 
  E^(-I \[CurlyPhi]) z`.